# html5 how to create a tab navigation system with multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner with web development and I have run into a issue which should be fairly simple. I am trying to create a website that will have a multiple tabs that will change the entire body of the page.  In order to improve readability I would like each tab to have it's own html file.
I am trying to use jQuery to do this but it doesn't appear to be working.
Here is my code:

```js
<!-- master.js -->



$(document).ready(function() {

  function replaceBody() {
    var homeLoad = $("body").load("home.html");
    $('body').replaceWith(homeLoad);
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
  TITLE
</title>

<head>
  Name
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>
  <script src="master.js"></script>

  <!-- loads scripts -->

</head>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="replaceBody();" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'About Us');">About Us</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Contact Us');">Contact Us</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Staff');">Staff</button>
</div>

<body id="body">
  this is the body you shouldn't see this
  <script>
    replaceBody();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
<!-- test.html-->

<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<h1 id ="h1">
  this is the top
</h1>

  </head>
  <head>



<html>
```

Comment: after `.load()` what you expect from this line `$('body').replaceWith(homeLoad);` to do??

Comment: But how is it not working. Also replaceWith removes the element along with it's children so if home.html does not have a <body> that would break things. I would use $("body").html(homeLoad); instead.

Comment: I changed it to what you recommended and it still didn't work. By didn't work I mean I don't see a change.  To open the file I am just running the index file in chrome.  I assume that the problem is that the other html files (home and test) are not loading in.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I actually messed that line up, it shouldn't be there.  I tried with and without it getting the same result.  I'm almost certain that the problem is that the house file isn't being loaded.  I just have no idea how to do this.